# How can I execute a jar file?

Tags: python

I used this string but it doesn't work:
**Error: Unable to access jarfile paper-1.18.1-92.jar**

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'paper-1.18.1-92.jar'])
```

Comment: The file 'paper-1.18.1-92.jar' either doesn't exist at all or at the very least doesn't exist in your current working directory. The clue is in the error message

Comment: try replace with jar's fullname(including path and quote around if containing spaces).

Comment: Is that error message from Python or from the started Java process? If it's the latter, you should ask yourself why that is the case. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **paper-1.18.1-92.jar** fullpath or **jar** file not exist.

in terminal , try  run **java -jar paper-1.18.1-92.jar** ?